# How to upload video or image file using keycdn in php

Tags: php, cdn

I'm using core php, I have also created a pull and push zone in keycdn account. My problem is I need to be able to upload a video or image file to a specified zone but I do not know how to do this?

[image]

now how to add my file in specific zone that i have created..

Thank you in advance..

Comment: Please add extra information. First of all a link to keycdn: https://www.keycdn.com and then show us what you've done so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should achieve your goal via this trick.

Directly not any method available but via ftp using PHP it is possible.

```
 <?php

 function uploadFTP($server, $username, $password, $local_file, $remote_file){
// connect to server
$connection = ftp_connect($server);

// login
if (@ftp_login($connection, $username, $password)){
    // successfully connected
}else{
    return false;
}

ftp_put($connection, $remote_file, $local_file, FTP_BINARY);
ftp_close($connection);
return true;
 }

 uploadFTP("ftp.keycdn.com", "yourusername", "yourpassword", "test.jpg", "/cdn/test.jpg");
 ?>
```